# Identifying this 6-contact audio-style connector

Tags: identification, connector

Can anyone help us identify this non-standard 6-pin audio-style connector that looks like a 4 pin jack with individual inner and outer rings at the base? Almost like a mini-jack combined with two separate RCA-style rings. Thanks!

[image: Connector diagram and pinout]

**Update:** I now believe it to be an "application-specific connector" that is a custom design and therefore not available?

Comment: Where did you get the drawing from?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Hi, it is copied from the manual of the multiplexer (MUX8-R2) which is an accessory to the PalmSens 4 potentiostat. However, their customer helpline could not tell me what it was

Comment: As for the update - I am pretty sure I saw such a connector somewhere, unfortunately can't recall where. Not in MUX8-R2 whatsoever context though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tensility International Corp
50-00009

[image: Tensility International Corp 50-00009]

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/tensility-international-corp/50-00009/6605493

I identified it through my [connector identification utility](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=round_conn&u=concentric_conn&o=phone_conn&f=phone_conn_3p5).

Comment: Incredible, thank you very much for that, this does indeed seem to be it. I think I see now why I couldn't find it before. That identification utility is amazing!

Comment: _That identification utility is amazing!_ Thank you! It's a work in progress. I hope you find it useful in the future.